# When isEditing is true, my texts are not aligned as seen in the picture. What is the reason?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, tableview

**Important :** **Tableview constraints codes are in a separate file.**

[image]

**Edit Button Code**

```
    @objc func didTapEdit(){
    if plansListTableView.isEditing {
        plansListTableView.isEditing = false
    }
    else {
        plansListTableView.isEditing = true
        
    }
}
```

**Constraints Code**

```
    private func addConstraints(){
    addSubview(planLabel)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            planLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            planLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20)
        ])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the label to `contentView`

```
private func addConstraints(){
    contentView.addSubview(planLabel)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        planLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
        planLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20)
    ])
}
```

And shortly

```
plansListTableView.isEditing.toggle()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It's working. But I did not understand this: What exactly does this code do ?  plansListTableView.isEditing.toggle() 

And another question :
After changing the rows, I run the application again and it goes back to the way it was. How can I save?

Comment: `plansListTableView.isEditing.toggle()` it changes the current value of `isEditing` so if its `true` it will be `false` and vice versa , use userdefaults to save the state